# How can I check if the first char in a string is '-'?

Tags: c++, string, text, char

In general, I need to check if a given string is a number. So I thought my function will check:
1. If the first char is '-' I want to check if there are only digits after it. 
 
2. If the first char is 0 the length of the string has to be less than 3.

The problem: I cannot find a way to get the first char in the string, like if I would do it in C (just look if it is equal to ASCII number), nor in Java, where I would compare strings with equals().

Comment: To see the first character in a string `s` (regardless of whether it's a C string or a C++ string) use `s[0]`. To see whether it's `'-'`, just do it: `if (s[0] == '-')`. Or, if you think your Java experience is relevant, you can compare C++ strings with `==`.

Comment: Using the `std::strtol` function is a good way to check if the string is a number

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy utility function to parse numbers based on streams:

```
template <class T>
bool try_parse_number(std::string_view s, T& v, const std::locale& locale)
{
    std::stringstream stream;

    stream.imbue(locale);

    stream << s;

    stream >> v;

    return !stream.fail();
}
```

Requires the includes `<sstream>`, `<string_view>` and `<locale>`, although you could strip the locale handling out.

You can further create a custom locale and a number facet to control number parsing to a greater degree.

Comment: This is very expensive, and ignores some of the requirements in the question.

Comment: @Pete Becker, I posted the answer based on the possibility of the extra requirements being an XY problem. Creating robust numeric string handling isn't cheap.

Comment: If you suspect that a stated requirement isn't real, ask in a comment to the question. That's what comment are for.

Answer (score -2):

I think in java it will be much easier since using a function --> s.charAt(0).  you can easily take the first character of that string and can store that character and later you can compare that to anything.

Comment: First, the question clearly specifies C++ in the tags. Second, every language can get the first character of a string. In fact, in C++ it's much simpler than in Java, since C++ is just `s[0]`